# How to make check box checked if equal data attribute value of list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a **`table`** with a **`button`** in each row and the last **`td`** has a **`ul`** with a different numbers of **`li`** . There is also a **`form`** with a different count of **`checkboxes`**.

What I need is a jQuery function that, when i click on this **`button`** in this **`tr`**, checks the **`data` attribute value** in the **`li`** and, if it's equal to the value of the checkbox/s, it will make it checked.

```js
$(function() {

  var liVal = $(".optList li").data("val"),
    chkVal = $("form-check-input").val();

  $(".editBtn").on("click", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (liVal == chkVal) {
      chkVal.attr("checked", "checked");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h2>Mark your checkboxes</h2>
      <form id="editForm">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="defaultCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
            checkbox 1
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" id="defaultCheck2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
            checkbox 2
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3" id="defaultCheck3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
            checkbox 3
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" id="defaultCheck4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck4">
            checkbox 4
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="2">2 - Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">

                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="3">3 - Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>

              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>

            </th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Cras justo odio</li>

              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/amr4web/pen/vYORVQM)

Comment: You may want to make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what specifically goes wrong. That could help us visualize what you're trying to do, and it's always nice to see a little effort.

Comment: @showdev
i really did a many different Technics on it ,and i working on it since 3 days ago but i did't get any result  
Now i updated the jquery code in codepin with a last approach i have
so please take a look at it

Comment: I added your updated code to your question. See [why/how to make a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/924299).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify the `data-val` values that are in the *same table row* as the clicked element.  Here's one way to accomplish it:

1. Find the row containing the clicked element by using jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).
2. Find the `.list-group-item` elements *inside* that row by using [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) or [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).
3. Build an array of the `data-val` values by using [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to return the value of each element's `data-val` attribute.
4. Select the checkbox elements directly by passing the array to their [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(function() {

  // define the checkbox elements
  let $checkboxes = $(".form-check-input");

  $(".editBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // find the row of the clicked element
    let $row = $(this).closest("tr");

    // build an array of the row's data values
    let liVals = $(".list-group-item", $row).map(function() {
      return $(this).data("val");
    }).toArray();

    // set the value of the checkboxes to the array of data values
    $checkboxes.val(liVals);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h2>Mark your checkboxes</h2>
      <form id="editForm">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="defaultCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
            checkbox 1
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" id="defaultCheck2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
            checkbox 2
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3" id="defaultCheck3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
            checkbox 3
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" id="defaultCheck4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck4">
            checkbox 4
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="2">2 - Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">

                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="3">3 - Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>

              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>

            </th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Cras justo odio</li>

              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

For further reference, see jQuery's [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

> `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`
>
> *selector*
>   Type: Selector
>   A string containing a selector expression
>
> *context*
>   Type: Element or jQuery
>   A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Answer (score 0):

So what you wanna do is get to `list-group-items` then you want to get all the Checkboxes and  then compare each list-group-item with every checkbox and if it matches you wanna set it's property `checked` to true

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".editBtn").click(function() {
          var TableRow = $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent();
          var OptList = TableRow.find(".optList");
          var ListGroup = OptList.find(".list-group");
          // List Items
          var ListItems = ListGroup.children();
          // Inputs
          var CheckBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input");
          // Check Each List Item with Every Checkbox Value
          $(ListItems).each(function(index) {
            var DataVal = $(this).attr("data-val");
            $(CheckBoxes).each(function(index) {
              var checkboxvalue = $(this).val();  
              if (DataVal === checkboxvalue) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
      // Event Listener to toggle Check Property
      $(".form-check-input").change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 JS -->
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container my-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <h2>Mark your checkboxes</h2>
          <form id="editForm">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="1"
                id="defaultCheck1"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                checkbox 1
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="2"
                id="defaultCheck2"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
                checkbox 2
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="3"
                id="defaultCheck3"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
                checkbox 3
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value="4"
                id="defaultCheck4"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck4">
                checkbox 4
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Options</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>
                </th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td class="optList">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">
                      1 - Cras justo odio
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="2">
                      2 - Dapibus ac facilisis in
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>
                </th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td class="optList">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="3">
                      3 - Morbi leo risus
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">
                      4 - Porta ac consectetur ac
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  editBtn">edit</a>
                </th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td class="optList">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">
                      1 - Cras justo odio
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>
                </th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td class="optList">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">
                      4 - Cras justo odio
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `edit` button then need to find parent `(tr)` then use `find()` method to get `[data-val]` inside `(tr)` then use `each()` method and inside each method set `data-val` value + `checkbox` value is equal(matched) then checked(true) something like below snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  // define the checkbox elements
  let allcheckBoxes = $(".form-check-input");
  $(".editBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove previous checked
    allcheckBoxes.prop('checked', false);

    // Find parent as <tr>
    let $row = $(this).parent().parent();

    $row.find('[data-val]').each(function(i,v){
      var listValues = $(this).attr('data-val');
      // If list value and checkbox value matched then checked -> true
      $('.form-check-input[value="'+listValues+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <h2>Mark your checkboxes</h2>
      <form id="editForm">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="defaultCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
            checkbox 1
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" id="defaultCheck2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
            checkbox 2
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3" id="defaultCheck3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
            checkbox 3
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" id="defaultCheck4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck4">
            checkbox 4
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="2">2 - Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="3">3 - Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  editBtn">edit</a></th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="1">1 - Cras justo odio</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary editBtn">edit</a>
            </th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td class="optList">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" data-val="4">4 - Cras justo odio</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```